# capistranoで設定される変数の値一覧の表示方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

`Capistrano`の3.3.x以降では `set :bundle_binstubs, nil` でデフォルトとなったようなのですが、このように `set`で指定できる変数の現在の値一覧を取得する方法はソースコードを確認する以外に何か方法はありますか？

コマンドラインから `cap --environment` のように読み出せたらそれが一番良いのですが。。

Answer (score 1):

以下のような task を`config/deploy.rb`に追加して`cap production config:display`すると production 環境での設定が一覧できます。

config/deploy.rb

```
namespace :config do
  task :display do
    Capistrano::Configuration.env.keys.each do |key|
      p "#{key} => #{fetch(key)}"
    end
  end
end
```

実行例

```
$ cap production config:display
"stage => production"
"scm => git"
"branch => master"
"deploy_to => /var/www/my_app_name"
"tmp_dir => /tmp"
"default_env => {}"
"keep_releases => 5"
"format => pretty"
"log_level => debug"
"pty => false"
"local_user => username"
"application => my_app_name"
"repo_url => git@example.com:me/my_repo.git"
"git_environmental_variables => {:git_askpass=>\"/bin/echo\", :git_ssh=>\"/tmp/my_app_name/git-ssh.sh\"}"
```